# getting timed out waiting for the condition when installing cert-manager with helm

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-20.04, cert-manager

helm install \

> cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager 
> --namespace cert-manager 
> --create-namespace 
> --version v1.13.0 
> --set installCRDs=true

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: 1 error occurred:
* timed out waiting for the condition

I did the steps in the site https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/.

i did try different versions but i got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ı solve the problem with "--debug --dry-run" "helm install   cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager  --namespace cert-manager  --version v1.7.1   --set installCRDs=true --debug --dry-run".

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already but worth checking. Do you have outbound (to the internets) access? Helm relies on being able to fetch stuff.

Another things to look for is how you allow deployments on your nodes. All are the nodes healthy? `kubectl get nodes -o wide` is a good way to check nodes.

A third option would be to check any logs/events.
`kubectl get events -A` would give you all the events from the cluster.

Is the namespaces cert-manager created?

```
kubectl get ns
```